# Add Trigger in UserControl

Tags: xaml, binding, styles, ismouseover

I have UserControl: Grid, Border, Image, Button. I need create Style for my UserControl and create Trigger in this style. 
My style:

```
<Style x:Key="SlideControlGrid" TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5"></Setter>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"></Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

But how I must Binding my styli with my UserControl in XAML file?

Comment: I need crate trigger if user hover the mouse on UserControl (No matter what element will be).

Answer (score 0):

Needed only add DynamicResource.
My Binding:

```
<UserControl.Style>
    <DynamicResource ResourceKey="SlideControlGrid"/>
</UserControl.Style>
```

My Style in another file Style.xaml:

```
<Style x:Key="SlideControlGrid" TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```